# first routerLink clicked doesn't work but any other link clicked after works

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application with a list of routerLinks on a page. When the page first loads, clicking any of these links changes the URL in the address bar correctly but no page load happens.

However, clicking another link works and navigates to the proper destination correctly.

This problem only happens on first page load. Everything works fine if I reload the page after the initial page load.

Links:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/organizations/', organization.id]" *ngFor="let organization of myOrganizations">
    <h4>{{organization.name}}</h4>
</a>
```

Router definition:

```
...
{
    path: 'organizations/:organizationId',
    component: OrganizationComponent,
    canActivate: [
      TokenGuard,
      IframeCaptureGuard,
      AuthGuard,
    ],
    data: {
      legacyUrl: '/#/dashboard/:organizationId',
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'reports/docs',
        redirectTo: 'reports/docs/info',
        canActivate: [
          TokenGuard,
          IframeCaptureGuard,
          AuthGuard,
        ],
        data: {
          legacyUrl: '/#/docreports/:organizationId',
        },
      },
    ]
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `pathMatch: 'full'` under `path: 'organizations/:organizationId'`